# calling of javascript function on datepicker input tag working on second action

Tags: php, javascript

I am taking on input tag that is calling a datepicker script for date. Now on onblur event of input tag, i am calling a javascript function that is working properly but on second time when i click on datepicker input for selecting value.

For the first time when i click on input tag and select a value from datepicker, nothing happens. But second time when i click on input tag and select a value from datepicker then my javascript function is working.

Here is the code:

```
// HTML code for input tag using datepicker script

<div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" size="12"  id="inputField" name="event_fromdate" readonly Placeholder="From Date" onblur="show_hide_fromdate();" />  
</div>

 // javascript function

 function show_hide_fromdate()
 {
     var fromdate=$('#inputField').val();
     var current_date = new Date();
     var userdate = new Date(fromdate);

     if(fromdate=="")
     {
         document.getElementById('msgFromDate').innerHTML = 'Enter From Date.';
     }
     else
     { 
         if(current_date.getDate()>userdate.getDate() || 
            current_date.getMonth()>userdate.getMonth() || 
            current_date.getFullYear()>userdate.getFullYear())
         {
             document.getElementById('msgFromDate').innerHTML = 'Invalid event date';
         }
         else
         {
             $('#msgFromDate').html('');
         }
     }
 }
```

Not getting the fault in this code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you problem is in `onBlur` event. I don't know why you call JS method using `onBlur` on `readonly` textfield. Can you explain this?

Comment: i have tried onchange also, but its also not working. can you suggest me suitable event?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you `onblur` events are not waiting for your `datepicker` input. I think what you need is something which can tell you that the text in your `textfield` has been changes. Something like this :

```
$("input[type=text]").change(function() {
    alert("Text changed");
});
```

[You can find a Working example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/sUCkB/)

Answer (score 0):

```
            function show_hide_fromdate()
             {
                 var fromdate=$('#inputField').val();
                 var current_date = new Date();

                 //comment this since first time this value of field is always empty
                 //I move it to validation part below

                 //var userdate = new Date(fromdate);

                 if(fromdate=="")
                 {
                    $('#msgFromDate').html('Enter From Date.');
                 }
                 else
                 { 
                    var userdate = new Date(fromdate);
                     if(current_date.getDate()>userdate.getDate() || 
                        current_date.getMonth()>userdate.getMonth() || 
                        current_date.getFullYear()>userdate.getFullYear())
                     {
                         $('#msgFromDate').html('Invalid event date'.');
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        // maybe you should echo something to know whether it worked well or not to debug
                         $('#msgFromDate').html('Valid');
                     }
                 }
             }
```

If above code does not work, you should use firebug to detect there has whether or not javascript error, maybe you should double check the output of datetime picker also.
I recommend you add "console.log('on blur')" into function to debug how this event behavior works.

Comment: firebug is not showing any error and console.log is just showing me on blur text.

Comment: Could you tell me the datepicker library which you are using?

Comment: ya its jDatePick.min.1.3.js